# Perl Net-SSLeay installation on AIX

Tags: perl, aix

When running make test for Net-SSLeay, this error is repeated.

Failed test 'use Net::SSLeay::Handle;'

at t/handle/local/05_use.t line 8.

Tried to use 'Net::SSLeay::Handle'.

Error:  Can't load '/ld01/perlsrc/Net-SSLeay-1.85/blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so' for module Net::SSLeay: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol EVP_DigestInit was referenced

from module /ld01/perlsrc/Net-SSLeay-1.85/blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so(), but a runtime definition

of the symbol was not found.

System is running AIX 7.1 Perl 5.24.4 and openssl 1.0.2o all compiled with gcc 6.3 (64-bit)

Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: As a start, find your `libcrypto.so` file and check if it exports this symbol: edit this command according to your system: `dump -Tv -X64 /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so | grep EVP_DigestInit` (Note: I've written some random thoughts about linking in AIX, you might want to read it: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with our installation of openssl 1.0.2o.  It was built as 32-bit.  We fixed it by rebuilding it with exporting OBJECT_MODE=64 before running config and make commands.

The sequence was as follows:
for openssl

export OBJECT_MODE=64

config -- make -- make test -- make install

For Net-SSLeay

export OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ssl (where openssl installed on our system)

perl Makefile.PL -- make -- make test -- make install

That got Net-SSLeay installed correctly.